# Running two commands with terraform local-exec provisioner

Tags: terraform, azure-cli, azure-machine-learning-service

I need to run two commands but the second command depends on the value of first command.

```
resource "null_resource" "datastore" {
  triggers = {
    always_run = "${timestamp()}"
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
     command = "az keyvault secret show --vault-name "nameofkv" --name "secretname" --query "value" && xargs -I{} az ml datastore attach-adls-gen2 --account-name [] --client-id [] --client-secret {} --file-system refined zone --name refinedzonetest --tenant-id [] --workspace-name [] --endpoint core.usgovcloudapi.net --subscription-id [] --resource-url https://storage.azure.com --authority-url https://login.microsoftonline.us"
}
 depends_on = [azurerm_machine_learning_workspace.ml]
```

}

the --secret {} depends on the first command. However, terraform gives an error saying "new line must exist after argument"

so If I put the second command in a new line, the second command does not run. any input in this issue or how I can improve it.

Comment: Have you tried using the native lookup in TF to fetch your value instead of local-exec? https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/data-sources/key_vault_secret